# Почему русский язык сохранил категорию рода, в то время как некоторые другие языки её утратили?

Tags: лексика, грамматика, существительные, род

Русский язык имеет категорию рода.

Однако есть ряд языков, например, испанский и английский, которые в прошлом имели категорию рода, но в процессе своего развития полностью или практически полностью утратили её, возможно, сохранив её только для личных местоимений.

К примеру, в английском языке нет различия в грамматическом роде: лошадь — женский род, дерево — средний, жёлудь — мужской, машина — женский, трактор — мужской и т. д.

Соответственно нет необходимости в согласовании по роду при построении предложения, что значительно упрощает грамматику.

Хотя в прошлом тот же английский имел полностью развитую систему родов:

> Although grammatical gender was a fully productive inflectional category in Old English, Modern English has a much less pervasive gender system, primarily based on natural gender and reflected essentially in pronouns only.
>
> Хотя грамматический род был полностью продуктивной флективной категорией в старом английском языке, современный английский имеет гораздо менее глубокую систему родов, главным образом основанную на природном поле и по существу отраженную только в местоимениях.
>
> [[Википедия](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender#Germanic:_English)]

---

- Почему же русский язык полностью сохранил систему категории рода?
- Для чего она служит?

Comment: Английский язык и систему падежных форм тоже утратил, вероятно уж заодно. А вот сложная система временных форм  осталась в английском языке, но упростилась в русском. Как вы думаете, нет ли здесь какой-то связи?

Comment: Постулат:Язык - пластичная масса, изменяющиеся под давлением времени и обстоятельств.

Comment: Могу добавить: разумно изменяющаяся.  Ходы сделаны разные, но каждому языку его выбор дал какое-то преимущество. Остается только подумать, кто выиграл при общем подведении итогов.  Наша  система падежных и родовых форм обеспечивает свободный порядок слов, а это важно для расстановки логических ударений.  А сложную систему времен мы слегка упростили, но подкорректировали  лексическим и др. средствами, так что и здесь все в порядке. Конечно, мы лучше :))

Comment: Конечно, мы лучше :)) – Sharon ======= Нам лучше. Потерявшие плачут. От этого постулата отталкиваясь, — у них следует спрашивать почему. Почему имевшие не хранили и не ведали, что обратной дороги нет.

Comment: Ну вот к примеру стол, какой у него может быть род? Не чушь ли это? Если уж и вводить систему родов в языке, то не такую как в русском. Да и вообще связывать грамматику и род смысла особого нет, хотя с другой стороны почему бы и нет, это не особо её обременяет.

Answer (score 1):

Так вышло исторически (возможно, нам и нашим предкам просто так больше понравилось:), что большинство славянских языков, в отличие от германских, сохранили категории индоевропейского языка, относящиеся к флексии: не только род, но и падежи, как заметили раньше. Эти грамматические категории помогают связывать слова в предложении и при этом сохранять свободный синтаксис: в русском можно, например, бех проблем поменять подлежащее и сказуемое местами. Английский язык - это язык аналитический. Из-за утраты падежей синтаксические отношения в предложении обозначаются прежде всего с помощью строгого порядка слов и артиклей. Гляньте, например, вот здесь подробности: https://tsput.ru/res/lang/yazykozn/jaz_zn_10.htm